# Selecting row with minimal value in one column, in a join query

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables: tblBusinesses, tblBusinessImages that are matched on tblBusinesses.fldID = tblBusinessImages.fldBusinessID like this:

```
tblBusinesses
=============
fldID | fldName | fldTitle | fldBody
-------------------------------------
1     | b1      | title1   | body1
2     | b2      | title2   | body2
3     | b3      | title3   | body3
4     | b4      | title4   | body4

tblBusinessImages
=============
fldID | fldFileName | fldTitle  | fldBusinessID | fldOrder
-----------------------------------------------------------
1     | img1.jpg    | img1title | 1             | 3
2     | img2.jpg    | img2title | 1             | 1
3     | img3.jpg    | img3title | 1             | 2
```

I want to write a query that gets for every business in tblBusinesses, the image in tblBusinessImages with minimal fldOrder. In other words, in the example I wrote above I want to get business b1, title1, body1 along with img2.jpg from tblBusinessImages (because it has minimal fldOrder in tblBusinessImages ).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the order always start at 1 per businessID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fldOrder` alwyas starts at one for each  `fldBusinessID` the query becomes

```
SELECT b.fldName, b.fldTitle, b.fldBody, i.fldFileName
FROM
    tblBusinesses b
    LEFT JOIN tblBusinessImages i
        ON (b.fldID = i.fldBusinessID AND i.fldOrder = 1)
```

If not, you will have to use subqueries.

```
SELECT b.fldName, b.fldTitle, b.fldBody, firstImage.fldFileName
FROM
    tblBusinesses b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT i.fldBusinessID, i.fldFileName
        FROM
            tblBusinessImages i
        WHERE
            i.fldOrder = (SELECT MIN(x.fldOrder) 
                          FROM tblBusinessImages x
                          WHERE x.fldBusinessID = i.fldBusinessID)
    ) firstImage
        ON b.fldID = firstImage.fldBusinessID
```

Note that the left join makes the query return also businesses having no image at all.

If you need only entries having images where the smallest order id can have any value:

```
SELECT b.fldName, b.fldTitle, b.fldBody, i.fldFileName
FROM
    tblBusinesses b
    INNER JOIN tblBusinessImages i
        ON b.fldID = i.fldBusinessID
WHERE
    i.fldOrder = (SELECT MIN(x.fldOrder)
                  FROM tblBusinessImages x
                  WHERE x.fldBusinessID = i.fldBusinessID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to get the ONE entry with the smallest fldOrder?
Didn't test this query:

```
SELECT b.fldName,b.fldTitle,b.fldBody,bi.fldFileName,bi.fldOrder 
FROM tblBuisnesses b 
INNER JOIN tblBuisnessImages bi ON bi.fldBusinessID=b.fldID ORDER BY b.fldOrder DESC LIMIT 1;
```